# How to find distance between two circle. OPENCV.Python

Tags: python, distance, opencv3.0

I have created code for detecting yellow and green colour through cam, and I have drawn circles where ever the colour has been detected. I want to find the distance between the two circles.
pls, give suggestions... Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: This is a math question. Probably not a very difficult one. Very likely it has been answered already somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pythagorean theorem

```
relativeX = circle1.x - circle2.x
relativeY = circle1.y - circle2.y

distance=sqrt(relativeX**2 + relativeY**2)
```